# Elasticsearch use icu_tokenizer from ICU Analysis plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, icu, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to install [ICU Analysis plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-icu) manually in Elasticsearch 1.4.0. I have downloaded elasticsearch-analysis-icu-2.4.1.jar, lucene-analyzers-icu-4.10.2.jar and icu4j-54.1.1.jar. The plugin appears normally in the console, but when I try to use icu_tokenizer, I get the following error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.analysis.icu.segmentation.DefaultICUTokenizerConfig]
```

This class actually exists in lucene-analyzers-icu. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the plugin installer instead of downloading the jar files manually as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/icu-plugin.html)?

```
./bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu/2.6.0
```

Run the command and restart the server. The plugin will be registered and functional.

Comment: I have tried but the plugin does not download, probably because of proxy. So I have to install it manually. For Elasticsearch 1.4.0, according to the documentation, the proper version is 2.4.2. The weird thing is that in the console log I see "analysis-icu" in the [INFO][plugins] line.

Comment: You should be able to specify the proxy information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-plugins.html#_proxy_settings

Comment: You are correct. The difference is that instead of icu4j-54.1.1, icu4j-53.1 was downloaded instead. The problem is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

[Document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu.html)

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```